# Alter behavior of Activities buttons on Modules

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have an outstanding module that I need to remove Quick Create functionality from record-creating actions, to use the New Record pages. [I understand the process on new Subpanels](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Developers/Customization/Modifying_Subpanel_Action_Buttons/index.html), but when I try to apply that process to actions inside the activities subpanel, they do not work consistently. Is there something different that I need to apply to when I work within the Activities subpanel?

Comment: can you post complete code which you have tried along with further details?